# Convert multiple rows in a single column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that has multiple columns, each column represent a different value of the `ID`. I would like to convert these value rows into a single column.

Sample data

```
ID             Elevation_1       Elevation_2      Elevation_3     Elevation_4
 279557         2070.934         2457.829         2954.444            0.000
 280485         2070.934         2457.829         2966.311         3226.203
```

Desired output

```
ID      Elevation
279557  2070.934
279557  2457.829 
279557  2954.444 
279557  0.000
280485  2070.934         
280485  2457.829  
280485  2966.311 
280485  3226.203
```

What I have tried so far

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

df = df%>% 
  gather(ID)
```

I also oooked into `pivot_longer` but couldn't quite understand how to use it in this case.

How can this be done using `dplyr`?

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_longer()` should do the trick.

Comment: Try `pivot_longer(df, cols = -ID)`

Comment: @Ben, that worked, thanks so much